# How to keep Vue bootstrap table from deforming/resizing on page zoom?

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2, bootstrap-4

I have a Vue b-table that contains a column of buttons for every day of the week, for some given time intervals like so: [table without zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGAoH.png).

My issue is that when a user of the site zooms in a lot (or uses a mobile device) the table squishes itself in a weird way, that makes the given time intervals be the columns of the table, instead of the days of the week. [It looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBTZo.png)

The code that I think is relevant is the following:

b-table in template:

```
<b-table bordered stacked="md" fixed :fields="this.tableFields" :items="schedule">
        <!-- A virtual column -->
        <template slot="time" slot-scope="data">
            <div class="timeslot-time">
                {{ data.item.start }} - {{ data.item.end }}
            </div>
        </template>

        <template v-for="day in days" :slot="day.key" slot-scope="data">
            <button type="button"
                    class="btn btn-secondary timeslot"
                    :data-start="data.item.start"
                    :data-end="data.item.end"
                    v-bind:class="timeslotClass(data.item.start, data.item.end, data.field.key)"
                    @click="toggleTimeslot(data.item.start, data.item.end, data.field.key)">
                &nbsp;
            </button>
        </template>
    </b-table>
```

The days to populate the table:

```
days: {
            type: Array,
            default: () =>
            [
                { key: 'Monday',    label: 'Mandag',  'class': 'text-center' },
                { key: 'Tuesday',   label: 'Tirsdag', 'class': 'text-center' },
                { key: 'Wednesday', label: 'Onsdag',  'class': 'text-center' },
                { key: 'Thursday',  label: 'Torsdag', 'class': 'text-center' },
                { key: 'Friday',    label: 'Fredag',  'class': 'text-center' },
                { key: 'Saturday',  label: 'Lørdag',  'class': 'text-center' },
                { key: 'Sunday',    label: 'Søndag',  'class': 'text-center' }
            ]
        }
```

Concat timeslots to the list:

```
tableFields() {
           //console.log([{ key: 'time', label: 'Tidspunkt' }].concat(this.days));
           return [{ key: 'time', label: 'Tidspunkt' }].concat(this.days);
        }
```

I've tried a few different things that I unfortunately haven't really kept track of. Any help towards making the table list buttons based on days instead of based on timeslots when zoomed would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I was overwhelmed by the amount of different information available in the bootstrap-vue documentation.
in the table definition

```
<b-table bordered stacked="md" fixed :fields="this.tableFields" :items="schedule">
```

the stacked tag forces this behaviour where rows are grouped as columns on small screens.

Changing the table to

```
<b-table bordered responsive :fields="this.tableFields" :items="schedule">
```

enables the desired behaviour where the part of the table that cannot be rendered on screen, will simply be put off screen allowing the user to scroll it into view.